# Problem when calling dictionary variables. TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, if-statement

I would like to print variable_1 of result1 and variable_3 of result2. I would like to try and continue to use similar syntax where I can specify the call of result1 and variable_1. **I want to print and recall both conditions.**

I get the following error: `TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str`

How can I solve?

```
def a():
    result1 = {}  
    if 2 > 1:
        print("yes 1")
        result1['variable_1'] = 2+2
        result1['variable_11'] = 'yes11'
                  
    else:
        print("no 1")
        result1['variable_2'] = 'no1'



    result2 = {}            
    if 3 < 2:
        print("yes 2")
        result2['variable_3'] = 'yes2'
    else:
        print("no 2")
        result2['variable_4'] = 'no2'
        
    return result1, result2

result1 = a()
result2 = a()

print(result1['variable_1'])
print(result2['variable_3'])
```

Comment: @ewong I tried. it does not work. KeyError: 'variable_3'

Comment: As expected, because `variable3` is only assigned under the condition `3 < 2`.

Comment: @ewong yes, but I want to print and recall both conditions. how can I do?

Comment: If you want the assignment to `result2['variable_3']` to actually take place, then you need to not put it inside an `if` statement that's unconditionally false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code as given has `a()` returns two values.

so what your code does is the following:

```
result1 = (result1, result2)
result2 = (result1, result2)
```

where the values within the parenthesis are variables based on
the variables within `a()`.

What you can do:

```
def a():
    result1 = {}  
    if 2 > 1:
        print("yes 1")
        result1['variable_1'] = 2+2
        result1['variable_11'] = 'yes11'
                  
    else:
        print("no 1")
        result1['variable_2'] = 'no1'



    result2 = {}            
    if 3 < 2:
        print("yes 2")
        result2['variable_3'] = 'yes2'
    else:
        print("no 2")
        result2['variable_4'] = 'no2'
        
    return result1, result2

result1, result2 = a()

print(result1['variable_1'])
print(result2['variable_3'])
```

A better way to lessen the confusion:

```
def a():
    r1 = {"variable_1": None,
          "variable_11": None,
          "variable_2": None}  
    if 2 > 1:
        print("yes 1")
        r1['variable_1'] = 2+2
        r1['variable_11'] = 'yes11'
    else:
        print("no 1")
        r1['variable_2'] = 'no1'

    r2 = {"variable_3": None,
          "variable_4": None}            
    if 3 < 2:
        print("yes 2")
        r2['variable_3'] = 'yes2'
    else:
        print("no 2")
        r2['variable_4'] = 'no2'
        
    return r1, r2

result1, result2 = a()

print(result1['variable_1'])
print(result2['variable_3'])
```

The problem also stems from the fact that you don't have default
values for `variable_3` since in `result2`, `3 < 2` is `False`, so `r2['variable_4']` is defined but `r2['variable_3']` isn't.

I set the default values to `None`; but you can set it to anything you wish.

That said, while the above code works, I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: I want to print and recall both conditions

Comment: What exactly do you mean by ```print and recall both conditions```?

Answer (score -1):

You are assigning two different variables both to the same thing: a tuple. What you really want is tuple unpacking. So instead of doing:

```py
result1 = a()
result2 = a()
```

Do:

```py
result1, result2 = a()
```

You do this because `a()` returns 2 different values, and you want to assign a var to each one. It’s equivalent to doing

```py
result1 = a()[0]
result2 = a()[1]
```

Also note that the condition `3 < 2` will never be true, so that value is never assigned.